# How to dynamically copy data to other sheets in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have one sheet with master data and four sheet with sub-sets of the data. I want to copy entire row contents to other sheets named ABM-I, ABM-II, ABM-III, & ABM-IV based on the 4th column "ABM". I need a dynamic link so that rows added, deleted, or altered here will automatically reflect in the four sheets with sub-sets of the data.

```
Sr#  Tel_Number  Amount  ABM    Date    
1    37162595    1600    4     11-04-13 
2    37352770    600     1     18-01-14 
3    37100234    1600    3     2-11-14  
4    37249662    1600    2     13-02-14 
5    37249723    1850    4     3-06-14  
6    37239708    600     2     17-03-14
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read ***[ask]*** to better understand how this site works. Then improve your question by updating it with details of what you have tried and what problems have stopped you.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  I would build 4 Queries, each filtering on the ABM column and delivering a filtered set of rows to the separate sheets. The auto-filter method is as easy to set up as regular Excel Filters:

https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Filter-a-table-b5610630-f5bf-4ba4-9217-a628f9b89353

When the master data sheet is updated, just go to the Data ribbon and choose Refresh All - the target tables will be emptied and reloaded.